# Sales per minute on Tiny Tower is at 0.00

Tags: tiny-tower

I used the time trick to skip over waiting time and then put it back to normal time (I was not stocking anything when I did this) I did lose 1 Bitizen in a time travel accident, and my sales per minute is stuck on 0.00- How do I fix this? I am playing on my iPhone 4S

Comment: It would also be good to give yoru feedback to the folks that make this game as it does sound like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Check the App store for upgrades to be sure that your Tiny Tower is the latest version.  Then Restart the Tiny Tower app in iOS.

If that doesn't do it, wait until the correct time naturally passes the latest time from your time traveling adventures.  This may be a new time travel bug.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do any time skip but my sales per minute turned to 0.0 also.

To fix it just let everything sell out. Have no inventory for anything and all the lights out on the stores. Log in each day to collect the rent. And when the all the lights are out on all the stores. Start back up. This worked on mine.